# debugging macro - unbound variable when calling

Tags: lisp

Essentially I am trying to code up a macro which will print out exactly some statement I am trying to evaluate, and the value it evaluates to.

What I have so far is the following:

```
(defmacro dbg (statement)
  (format t "~a: ~a" statement (eval statement)))
```

and by typing the following into the slime repl: (dbg (* 2 2)) I get the desired result which is:

```
"(* 2 2): 4"
```

However when I try to use it in the following function **:

```
(defun get-start-position (curr-prime)

  (dbg (/ (- (* curr-prime curr-prime) 3) 2))

  (/ (- (* curr-prime curr-prime) 3) 2))
```

slime reports that curr-prime is unbound (and just sticking everything in a let doesn't help). To be more specific the act of trying to compile the function get-start-position results in:

```
2 compiler notes:

primes.lisp:27:3:
  error:
    during macroexpansion of (DBG (- # 3)). Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to intercept:

    The variable CURR-PRIME is unbound.

primes.lisp: 29:9:
  note:
    deleting unreachable code
    ==>
      CURR-PRIME

Compilation failed.
```

Presumably (and the second warning baffles me), the error comes about because the macro is expanded before the function which calls it gets a chance to bind curr-prime to some value (am I correct here?). That said I have no clue how to get round this issue

What am I doing wrong?

---

** for what its worth I am coding up a prime sieve where the indicator array has the following elements:

(3,5,7,9, ...)

This particular function will get me the index of the square of a given prime

Comment: Remember: a macro should generate code. You don't generate code.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig I now understand what you mean. Studying the solution given, and observing I never quoted anything, I see that I was evaluating the (format t blah) inside the macro instead of generating the code I wanted). thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a pro on Lisp macros, but this will do:

```
(defmacro dbg (statement)
  (let ((result (gensym)))
  `(let ((,result ,statement))
     (format t "~a: ~a" ',statement ,result)
     ,result)))
```

then

```
(dbg (* 2 2))

=> (* 2 2): 4
4
```

and

```
(defun get-start-position (curr-prime)
  (dbg (/ (- (* curr-prime curr-prime) 3) 2)))

(get-start-position 1)

=> (/ (- (* CURR-PRIME CURR-PRIME) 3) 2): -1
-1
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this does indeed work (though it now indicates a bug (in my design) I'll need to fix in that I ought to find a way of expanding curr-prime to its value when the macro is called)

Comment: Almost. It's not a good idea to use the name `result`. That's what the function `GENSYM` is for: it generates a symbol, which can not conflict with other names.

Comment: @HexedAgain Just add a `(dbg curr-prime)` as the first form of `get-start-position`.

Comment: @uselpa, that is the way I have been using it so far; being honest with myself I'm probably not quite ready for improving it as I would like at my current level (yet!). Again, thanks for the help!